# Spring boot 2.1.5 dont log existing endpoint

Tags: spring-boot

I have a problem to log any existing endpoint in spring boot application. 
This is my simple project with one rest endpoint. When i run the application in console i cannot see any logs about mappings. In older spring boot version, spring always logs automatically all existing mappings in project. What I should configure to make spring boot log my endpoint mapping like below:

> 2019-08-05 18:22:15.317 TRACE 11435 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped [/**] onto ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]

This is the repository to my example project https://bitbucket.org/powrseba/spring-boot-example/src/singleModule/

Comment: I have tried all of that things and it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Okey as @davidxxx wrote it is duplicate. I don't wrote the paragraph about changes in Spring Boot 2.1 that default logs configuration have changed.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#logging-refinements

> Logging Refinements
>
> Spring Framework 5.1 revisited the debug logging output while working on web  >applications (Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux). If you are trying to debug an >application and you want to restore Spring Boot 2.0 style logging you should add the >following to your application.properties:
>
> `logging.level.web=debug`

Post to close :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to logs existing mapping to logs ?
There is a lot of alternative with more value that permit you to access existing apis.

`Spring Boot` provide a dependency to `Actuator`.  It will exposing a dedicated endpoint called mappings returning existing mappings accessible under `/actuator/mappings`.

Actuator supply a lot of features like health indicator, application information, logger value, properties, etc.

It's completely integrated with spring and spring-security. If you never heard about it, just take a look.

Comment: I dont need but i am curious why when I have create project by spring initializer in the past before spring boot 2.0.0 i always have that feature by default but now when i create project in spring boot higher then 2.1.0 i dont have that logs

Comment: And if the actuator was not correctly mapped, how to diagnostic all mapped urls ?  I don't tell that logging these information systematically is a good idea but to get this information as soon as the spring boot startup may be interesting in some cases/things to fix. Overall when you have to restart 10 times because you don't understand why an URL doesn't work.